# Does adding methods to a Java class boost the memory usage of its instances?

Tags: java, memory-management, methods

Adding member variables to a class certainly boosts the memory footprint of its instances on the heap, but what about a class's methods?

For example, if I have a class composed of a single StringBuilder, but keep adding dozens of methods to manipulate that StringBuilder, will each instance of that class take up proportionally more memory as I add more methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, adding methods does not increase the footprint of the object, only the footprint of the compiled code. In other words, the per-instance memory cost is zero.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no, it will not add more memory to each object living in the heap. The only thing that will happen is when the class is first loaded, it will also load this methods.

Comment: Well, this answer understates it a bit.  The Oracle Hotspot VM compiles bytecode down to native code once a method has been invoked some number of times, and at this point it also does dynamic method inlining.  So other things do happen when you add more methods—it's just that this is a cost of the *class*, not of the *instances*.

Answer (score 2):

This is VM specific, but for the Oracle Hotspot VM that everybody uses, no, the instance size is not affected.